# IntelliJ / NPM not installing React Library framer-motion: - asks me to install loop

Tags: reactjs, intellij-idea, framer-motion

Does anyone have any insight on why my intelliJ keeps asking me to install this React library.

Ive installed it multiple times with no errors occurring and ive tried reinstalling Npm. Also tried another library called Spring - again same problem it just seems to ignore my install.

If no one has a clue i will next try moving all the files to a new React project.

[Link to screenshot as im under 10 rep][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLX9d.png

Comment: the error is "module is not listed in `package.json` dependencies". Do you have this module specified in your  `package.json` `"dependencies":` list?

Comment: Package,json dependencies list ---- "name": "portfoliowebsitemain",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "eslint": "8.22.0",
    "framer-motion": "^8.5.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-animations": "^1.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-spring": "^9.6.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },

Comment: @lena please see above if you see anything?

Comment: is it the only `package.json` that you have in your app?